# Why am I getting this error? TypeError: this.state.items.sort is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have tried to reference items in my suggestion variable but for some reason anytime I have tried to reference it I get an error. Can't I reference a state in a variable? What can I do to fix this error?

```
const { Search } = Input;
class AutoCompleteText extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            suggestions: [],
            text: '',
            items: [{ name:'', currentName:''}]
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let URL = 'http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters';
        let HEADERS = {'content-type':'application/json', 'authorization':'sdjfjdskfj45j4ekj'};

        axios.get(URL, HEADERS)
        .then((response) => {
            let usersData = response.data;
            let items = [];
            for (let i=0; i<usersData.length; i++) {
                let currentName = usersData[i]['name'];
                items.push({'name': currentName});
            }
            this.setState({items: "n;ajsdfasd"});  
            console.log(items);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

    onTextChanged = (x) => {
        const value = x.target.value;
        let suggestions = [];
        if (value.length > 0) {
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, 'i')
            suggestions = (this.state.items).sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
        }
        this.setState(() => ({suggestions, text: value}));
        console.log(suggestions)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.setState({items: "n;ajsdfasd"});
```

Here you are setting items as a string. It is no longer an array.

Change it to

```
this.setState({items: items});
```

Comment: PERFECT that worked thank you! Its not working properly still but that error went away. THANK YOU SO MUCH1